# bit.dev cli test snapshots not updating

Tags: bit.dev

bit.dev CLI doesn't seems to honor `-u` flag while running `bit test <component-pattern>`. I have snapshots generated for component already and test fails with

```
4 snapshots failed from 1 test suite. Inspect your code changes or re-run jest with `-u` to update them.
```

When trying to pass `-u` flag as `bit test <component-pattern> -u`, it fails with

```
Unknown argument: u
```

How can we update snapshots using bit cli test command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't.
Unless you extend your the environment you are using and add this logic (you can add this flag to be passed to the jest config).